# Stochastic process with no mutually exclusive events over time.

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, independence

Let $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be a strictly stationary stochastic process and let $\mathcal{F}_{s}^{t}$, where $s\le t$,  be the sigma algebra $\sigma(X_s,\ldots,X_t)$. I am interested in the following property:

> Suppose $A\in\mathcal{F}_{-\infty}^{t}$ and $B\in\mathcal{F}_{t+1}^{\infty}$ are such that $P(A)>0$ and $P(B>0)$, then $P(A\cap B)>0$.

Does anyone know whether this property has a certain name, or is implied by some common property such as mixing conditions or something like that? Clearly independence is enough, but I was hoping to go more general.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Let $X$ be a Markov chain with forbidden transitions, i.e., a zero in its transition matrix.  (For example, a $\pm$ random walk mod $3$.)  Such a process can be  ergodic, mixing, strongly mixing, but yet violates your hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you suggest is violated by $2$-dependent processes. Indeed, let $\left(\varepsilon_t\right)_{t\in\mathbb Z}$ be an i.i.d. sequence such that $\mathbb P\left(\varepsilon_0=1\right)=1/2=\mathbb P\left(\varepsilon_0=0\right)$. Define $X_t=\varepsilon_t+\varepsilon_{t+1}$ and consider $A=\left\{X_t=0\right\}$ and $B:=\left\{X_{t+1}=2\right\}$. Then 
$$\mathbb P\left(A\right)=\mathbb P\left(\varepsilon_t=0,\varepsilon_{t+1}=0\right)=1/4;$$
$$\mathbb P\left(B\right)=\mathbb P\left(\varepsilon_t=1,\varepsilon_{t+1}=1\right)=1/4$$
and $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

If $A\in\mathcal{F}_{-\infty}^{t}$ and $B\in\mathcal{F}_{t+1}^{\infty}$, then the best we can say in general is that 
$$\mathbb P\left(A\cap B\right)\geqslant \mathbb P\left(A\right)\mathbb P\left(B\right)-\alpha(1).$$